# Spring MVC not autowiring in HTTP POST, but doing in Ajax on the same controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a weird situation.

I need to manage a progress-augmented upload that needs to work with [ancient.ie](https://modern.ie) version 9.

Upload can be only done via submitting an `iframe` POST, and we do that leveraging Flow js. During upload, an Ajax period request is issued to monitor the progress of the upload and fill the gauge on the UI.

### Code

```
@Scope("request")
@PreAuthorize("hasFunction('DMS')")
@Controller("/secure/admin/pages/dms/fileRepository")
@RequestMapping("/secure/admin/pages/dms/fileRepository")
public class FileRepositoryController extends BaseController
{
    private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private FileRepositoryManager fileRepositoryManager;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventMulticaster eventDispatcher;

@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadProgress",
            method =
    {
            RequestMethod.POST,
            RequestMethod.GET
    })
    public PhoenixResponse uploadProgress(HttpSession session)
    {

        UploadInfo info = (UploadInfo) session.getAttribute(UploadInfo.SESSION_KEY);

        if (info == null)
        {
            log.warn("Upload info not found in session");
            return info().withSingleton(new UploadInfo());
        }

        PhoenixResponse res;

        switch (info.getStatus())
        {
            case DONE:
            {
                session.removeAttribute(UploadInfo.SESSION_KEY);
                res = success().withAlert("Upload OK", DEFAULT_ALERT_TIMEOUT);
                break;
            }
            case PROGRESS:
            case START:
            case PROCESSING:
            {
                res = info();
                break;
            }
            case ERROR:
            {
                res = error().withAlert("Errore upload");
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        res = res.withSingleton(info)
                 .withResponseCode(info.getStatus()
                                       .name());

        return res;

    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/uploadIframe",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public final @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Void> uploadIframe(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpSession session)
    {
        upload(file, session); //Redirect to Ajax-ready method

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public final PhoenixResponse upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpSession session) //Requires modern browser
    {
        UploadInfo info = (UploadInfo) session.getAttribute(UploadInfo.SESSION_KEY);

        log.debug("Upload request received");

        FileUploadDTO result;

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty())
        {

            String uploadFileName = IOUtils.getFileSafeName(file.getOriginalFilename());
            log.debug("upload file: " + uploadFileName + " user: " + getUsername());
            try
            {
                FileDescriptor fd;
                try (InputStream is = file.getInputStream())
                {
                    fd = fileRepositoryManager.store(is, uploadFileName, AdminModule.ID, getUsername());
                }
                result = new FileUploadDTO(fd.getName(), fd.getLength(), fd.getMimeType(), fd.getId());
                eventDispatcher.multicastEvent(new FileUploadEvent(this, fd));
            }
            catch (IOException | RuntimeException ex)
            {
                info.setStatus(UploadState.ERROR);
                log.error("Error uploading file", ex);
                return error().withAlert(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else
            return error();

        if (info != null)
            info.setStatus(UploadState.DONE);

        return info().withSingleton(result);
    }

}
```

Explanation: we have two upload methods. One is Ajax-ready and the other responds on POST requests. In fact the `uplodaIframe` method returns a classic `200` empty page. But since the code is the same it just redirects the call to the Ajax-ready method, which return an unused response object

### Problem

When invoking `/uploadProgress`, though it doesn't use any `@Autowired` bean, all autowires are set.

When invoking `/uploadIframe` all beans are null despite there no `required=false` on their autowires

I also found an interesting difference in the stack trace:

/uploadProgress

```
FileRepositoryController.uploadProgress(HttpSession) line: 106  
FileRepositoryController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7ccffed3.invoke(int, Object, Object[]) line: not available  
MethodProxy.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 204  
CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint() line: 720 
CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 157 
MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 68 
CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 179 
CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 655  
FileRepositoryController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8768d018_2.uploadProgress(HttpSession) line: not available 
GeneratedMethodAccessor1992.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available    
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606
```

/uploadIframe

```
FileRepositoryController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8768d018_2(FileRepositoryController).upload(MultipartFile, HttpSession) line: 144  
FileRepositoryController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8768d018_2(FileRepositoryController).uploadIframe(MultipartFile, HttpSession) line: 118    
GeneratedMethodAccessor1993.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available    
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606
```

Comment: Why on earth is that bean even request scooped? You aren't keeping state so making it a scoped bean is only complicating things, just make it a singleton. Also the difference is due to the fact that the method is final and as such not proxy able.

Comment: Sorry, I **tried** to make bean request-scoped. It was originally not. I am also removing the `final` modifier that was inherited from old code (in which had a sense to exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly understand why, but the problem was related to the `final` modifier of the two method.

Removing `final` had the beans autowired correctly. Kudos to @M.Deinum